# Whole Module Optimization - place all swift files from pods in main project?

Tags: ios, swift, clang, cocoapods, llvm

I read [this article](https://swift.org/blog/whole-module-optimizations/) about Whole Module Optimization (WMO). I am curious if I fully benefit from the optimizations if I place all the swift files from `Cocoapods` directly in my main project, since then, WMO sees all the swift files as a whole and can make optimizations like function inlining and generic specialization across my whole project, instead of per module (pod).

How does WMO works for multiple pods? Does it do WMO per module/pod? If so, I think a project can benefit even more from WMO if all the swift files are in the same project, since then WHO can optimize everything as a whole, instead of per module/pod. Or am I missing something?

So before going in production, remove all the pods, place the .swift files directly in the project and run WMO looks to me like I will benefit more from WMO than not doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Whether it's worth the trouble is another question, but yes to all of it.

(I've done it this way for years, and still do in some projects, but on newer projects I've given up and accepted that frameworks are life and just let CocoaPods be CocoaPods. It's just too much work to do it by hand. But that's opinion. The answer is "yes.")

Comment: Please be more specific why you think it will benefit. Just "Yes" is not an answer.